# Prevent page reloading on dialog close

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I close the dialog box, the page is reloaded. How can I prevent it?

```js
  function getDialog(url){
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#content').html(result);       

                $.mobile.changePage('#dialog', 'pop', true, true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: When you close a dialog, it goes back to previous page. What's exactly happening?

Comment: On first page I have a function that gets content from ajax. When I click on links it opens dialog box, when I close it, the first page reloaded, the function works again.